# Clean logarithmic scale (loglog) plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, loglog

I have this `loglog` plot that I would like to clean up on y-axis which, you see below, is a bit of a mess.

[image: my plot]

I would like the plot to look like this:

[image: expected results]

More specifically I want to remove the ticks that are visible between the values (`0`, `10e-2`, `10e-4`, `10e-6`, `10e-8`, `10e-10`). How to achieve this?

Comment: something like `grid on` and also `set(gca,'fontsize',14) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn the minor ticks off:

```
y = logspace(1,-8,5);
x = logspace(0.5,2,5);
loglog(x,y)
grid on
ax = gca;
ax.YAxis.MinorTick = 'off'; % and the same for the X-axis
ax.FontSize = 16;
```

[image: minorTick]

Comment: Cheers! In addition I added ax.YMinorGrid = 'off' to get rid of the minor grid lines that was still there for me